# Is there a way to figure out when was my ipad / iphone disconnected from charge cable?

Tags: iphone, ipad, charging, logs

Ok, it may sounds weird but I just found my iPad in the **trash** (yeah you've read it right haha). So the last thing I remember that I connected it to the charge cable. After I arrived home I've found it in the trash disconnected from the cable. I thought I may can find more information from some **history of logs** or something.

It's a **mystery**.

- Was it my girlfriend?
- Or our cats?

Can you help me figure this out?

Comment: Cats in particular - https://m.imgur.com/gallery/vdLE8dJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually is a way to find out when your iPad was disconnected from the charging cable. If you have iOS 12, you can go to `Settings -> Battery` and look at the graph.

[image: this is a picture I found off google]

The part with the light green shadow with the little lightning symbol is the time when it is charging. When it gets unplugged, the light green section will stop and you can tell when your iPad was unplugged.

Comment: Excellent answer, existing person.

Comment: Thank you! Too bad my iPad Mini does not support iOS 12, so I just closed the investigation over lack of evidence. :)

Comment: Now we just have to find out where the cat was, at that time ;) \s

Answer (score 3):

In my professional experience I say it was definitely the cats.

[image]